# in Xcode how can i show local notification of both "foreground and background" mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate, unusernotificationcenter, usernotifications

my below code only sends local notifications when foreground. how can i show local notification of both "foreground and background" mode?
can anyone provide a code ?
thank you
o.k

```
@main
struct ozApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate


    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().onAppear {   self.send()  }
            
        }
    }

func send(){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
            if success {
                print("All set!")
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
         
        
        var content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Message1"
        content.subtitle = "subtitle"
        content.body = "body"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        var request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString , content: content, trigger: nil)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

and i also have this section

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Show local notification in foreground
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
}
// Conform to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to show local notification in foreground
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the trigger, the below code works fine

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
var content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
 content.title = "Message1"
         content.subtitle = "subtitle"
         content.body = "body"
         content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
         var request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString , content: content, trigger: trigger)
         UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

[image]

Comment: it only triggers when the app is foreground..... you can add this and during the 10 seconds put the app in the background and see it docent trigger --- code:::::   let secondsToDelay = 10.0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + secondsToDelay)
        request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString , content: content, trigger: nil)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)

Comment: I tried it on background too, it work fine but without async after just set the trigger time interval .

Comment: just set the trigger time interval .... do i have to set it for it to work  ? when its nil it fires imm.

Comment: ??? didn't get an answers from you

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + gSecondsToDelay) {
            self.executeRepeatedly()
        }